# How can I modify DataFrame column value using another column as a parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe(data) like these:

```
                     mac  len      corp                               detail
18025           14:1F:BA    8  IeeeRegi          IEEE Registration Authority
18026  14:1F:BA:00:00:00   10  Shenzhen  Shenzhen Mining Technology Co.,Ltd.
18027  14:1F:BA:10:00:00   10   Gloquad                                  NaN
18028  14:1F:BA:20:00:00   10  Deutsche      Deutsche Energieversorgung GmbH
18029  14:1F:BA:30:00:00   10   Private                                  NaN
```

How can I get the below results using the method such as data['mac'].str.slice(0,data['len'])].

```
              mac  len      corp                               detail
18025    14:1F:BA    8  IeeeRegi          IEEE Registration Authority
18026  14:1F:BA:0   10  Shenzhen  Shenzhen Mining Technology Co.,Ltd.
18027  14:1F:BA:1   10   Gloquad                                  NaN
18028  14:1F:BA:2   10  Deutsche      Deutsche Energieversorgung GmbH
18029  14:1F:BA:3   10   Private                                  NaN
```

I know the apply method is OK:

```
def sub_mac(x):
    return x.mac[:x.len]
data.mac = data.apply(sub_mac, axis=1)
```

or

```
data.mac = data.apply(lamda x: x.mac[:x.len], axis=1)
```

But I wanna know if there is another method to handle it?
for example, the method like sql:

```
select SUBSTRING(mac, 0, len) as mac_sub from data;
```

thx.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Source DF:

```
In [8]: df
Out[8]:
                     mac  len      corp                               detail
18025           14:1F:BA    8  IeeeRegi          IEEE Registration Authority
18026  14:1F:BA:00:00:00   10  Shenzhen  Shenzhen Mining Technology Co.,Ltd.
18027  14:1F:BA:10:00:00   10   Gloquad                                  NaN
18028  14:1F:BA:20:00:00   10  Deutsche      Deutsche Energieversorgung GmbH
18029  14:1F:BA:30:00:00   10   Private                                  NaN
```

Solution:

```
In [9]: df['mac'] = df.groupby('len')['mac'].transform(lambda x: x.str[:x.name])
```

Result:

```
In [10]: df
Out[10]:
              mac  len      corp                               detail
18025    14:1F:BA    8  IeeeRegi          IEEE Registration Authority
18026  14:1F:BA:0   10  Shenzhen  Shenzhen Mining Technology Co.,Ltd.
18027  14:1F:BA:1   10   Gloquad                                  NaN
18028  14:1F:BA:2   10  Deutsche      Deutsche Energieversorgung GmbH
18029  14:1F:BA:3   10   Private                                  NaN
```